# Is there some other measurement that describe the ability to absorb some spicified range of frequencies of sound?

Tags: acoustics

There are a variety of materials could be used to absorb sound in order to soundproof.

Absorption coefficient is used to describe the absorb sound ability of the material.

Is the following guess true:
some materials are good at absorbing some spicified range of frequencies of sound (such as little girl screaming), while some other materials are good at absorbing some other spicified range of frequencies of sound, such as car's engine.

If yes, is there some other measurement that describe the ability to absorb some spicified range of frequencies of sound, like little girl screaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absorption coefficient is usually specified by the manufacturer over some frequency range, in dB of loss. High frequencies are commonly absorbed by light, fluffy materials with a lot of air in them. Low frequencies are commonly absorbed by heavy materials with little or no elasticity.

Comment: Well, technically speaking, the absorption coefficient is a dimensionless quantity, which should be in the range [0, 1]. Nevertheless, the manufacturers usually provide the Airborne Sound Insulation capabilities of the material in dB (although this is most common for partitions). I believe this is what you mean right?

Comment: yes yes.   ...-NN